# Amazon Fees are not updating in Magento Orders when importing orders using M2E pro

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, m2e-pro

I'm using M2Epro in a Magento site. When syncing the Amazon Orders to Magento store, it creates the orders and products correctly but the Amazon Fee always shows 0 (Zero) in the Order details in Magento.

I have created screenshots to describe the issue more clearly:

1. See the Amazon Orders import log [image]

   - Amazon orders are imported and Magento orders created with similar info. Note the Order #, Magento Order #. An equivalent Magento Order is created for each Amazon order.
2. See the details of the Amazon Order [image].
3. See the details of the Magento Order counterpart of the Amazon order [image] . Note the Amazon fee shows 0 but the actual fee is not 0. We have to update it with real value

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible and can only be found in your monthly reconciliation report from Amazon. However as M2EPro is a 3rd party extension. This question would be better asked via their support channels.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your a 3rd party provider you should be able to tap into the Amazon data feed via API and get access to the fees the same way you do it with PayPal/eBay. We have used several 3rd party providers over the years and its never been an issue. This is something M2E should put on the wishlist for future improvements for sure.